# GET file from internal stage via NodeJS SDK 1.9.2

Tags: snowflake-stage

I am using the Snowflake NodeJS driver `snowflake-sdk` (Version 1.9.2). New to Snowflake overall and although I was able to establish connection and queries I am struggling with the concept of downloading files from an internal stage. I do have the files uploaded in the stage. Just not seeing how to download them.

I do see there is support for `GET` in snowsql and gosnowflake ... how is this accomplished with the JS sdk?